# How to retreive and use the outproc of a Postgres type to convert a Datum to cstring?

Tags: c, postgresql, server-side

I am trying to write a PostgreSQL (16.x) stored procedure in C to print an arbitrary typed argument as a C-string. From what I understand, each type has its [input and output functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xtypes.html). So, my plan is to

1. get the Oid of the argument type, (`extract_variadic_args`)
2. retrieve the `outproc` of that type by the Oid (`get_outproc_oid` below)
3. call the outproc to convert the argument's Datum to c-string. (`OidOutputFunctionCall`)

The code I have so far (listed below) compiles, but gives strange results. Instead of print the first argument as strings, it prints some random large number. I am not familiar with server-side postgresql C programming. Hence the question here.

*Could someone help explain what went wrong and how to make the string conversion work?*

My code so far:

Helper C function:

```c
// for var2cstring
#include "utils/typcache.h"
#include "utils/fmgroids.h"
#include "utils/lsyscache.h"

 void
 get_outproc_oid(Oid typoid, Oid *outfuncoid) //adapted from json_categorize_type()
 {
     bool        typisvarlena;
  
     /* Look through any domain */
     typoid = getBaseType(typoid);
  
     *outfuncoid = InvalidOid;
  
     switch (typoid)
     {
         case BOOLOID:
             *outfuncoid = F_BOOLOUT;
             break;
  
         case INT2OID:
         case INT4OID:
         case INT8OID:
         case FLOAT4OID:
         case FLOAT8OID:
         case NUMERICOID:
             getTypeOutputInfo(typoid, outfuncoid, &typisvarlena);
             break;
  
         case DATEOID:
             *outfuncoid = F_DATE_OUT;
             break;
  
         case TIMESTAMPOID:
             *outfuncoid = F_TIMESTAMP_OUT;
             break;
  
         case TIMESTAMPTZOID:
             *outfuncoid = F_TIMESTAMPTZ_OUT;
             break;
  
         case JSONOID:
             getTypeOutputInfo(typoid, outfuncoid, &typisvarlena);
             break;
  
         case JSONBOID:
             getTypeOutputInfo(typoid, outfuncoid, &typisvarlena);
             break;
  
         default:
             /* Check for arrays and composites */
             if (OidIsValid(get_element_type(typoid)) || typoid == ANYARRAYOID
                 || typoid == ANYCOMPATIBLEARRAYOID || typoid == RECORDARRAYOID)
             {
                 *outfuncoid = F_ARRAY_OUT;
             }
             else if (type_is_rowtype(typoid))   /* includes RECORDOID */
             {
                 *outfuncoid = F_RECORD_OUT;
             }
             else
             {
         /* any other builtin type */
         getTypeOutputInfo(typoid, outfuncoid, &typisvarlena);
             }
             break;
     }
 }
```

main C function:

```c
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(var2cstring);
//var2cstring
Datum var2cstring( PG_FUNCTION_ARGS )
{
     int         nargs;
     int         i;
     Datum      *args;
     bool       *nulls;
     Oid        *types;
     Oid        elemtype;
     Oid        outfuncoid;

     /* fetch argument values to build the object */
     nargs = extract_variadic_args(fcinfo, 0, false, &args, &types, &nulls);

     //elemtype = get_fn_expr_argtype(fcinfo->flinfo, 0);
     elemtype = types[0];
     
     get_outproc_oid(elemtype, &outfuncoid);
     Datum val = args[0];
     char *sometext = OidOutputFunctionCall(outfuncoid, val);

     PG_RETURN_CSTRING(sometext);
}
```

The sql file:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION var2cstring(VARIADIC "any") RETURNS INT
        AS '$libdir/vc_agg'
        LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Test data:

```sql
drop table if exists t2;
create table t2(v1 text, v2 text);
insert into t2 values
  ('Bob','Tom'),
  ('Tom', 'Bob'),
  ('Rich', 'Rich');

drop table if exists t3;
create table t3(v1 int, v2 int);
insert into t3 values
  (1,2),
  (2,1),
  (3,3);

select var2cstring(v1, v2) from t2;

select var2cstring(v1, v2) from t3;
```

I expect to get the first column v1 back, but instead got some large numbers:

```
 var2cstring 
-------------
  1373702072
  1373702072
  1373702072
(3 rows)

 var2cstring 
-------------
  1373702072
  1373702072
  1373702072
(3 rows)
```